# How to dynamically embed YouTube Videos into website?

Tags: html, youtube, youtube-api, velo

I have a YouTube channel which is starting to get traction.I would like to save my domain names, so for time being I want my YouTube Videos to automatically in my Website. How can I do have this?

FYI: my website is in http://wix.com

Comment: Havent used Wix before, but presumably this widget would help https://support.wix.com/en/article/adding-a-youtube-feed-to-wix-video

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consult the Wix team or check their docs like this [Adding a Video from YouTube](https://support.wix.com/en/article/adding-a-video-from-youtube) post on their support page:

> **To add a single YouTube video:**
>
> 1. Click Add  on the left side of the Editor.
> 2. Click Video. Click the
> 3. YouTube video, or drag it to the relevant location. Click Change
> 4. Video. Enter the video's web address, or click Search Videos to find
>      and select your video.
>
> **To add a YouTube video using Wix Video:**
>
> 1. Add Wix Video.
> 2. Add a YouTube video to your video library.